# Why does DD'ing a raw image change the image when read back

Tags: linux, partitioning, images, dd

I have a .RAW image. The image contains a single partition.

I have created a loopback based device. I created a single partition on that device.

I'm writing my .RAW to the partition.

```
sudo dd if=/tmp/image.raw of=/dev/loop25p1 status=progress
```

I then read the partition

```
 sudo dd of=/tmp/image.dd.raw if=/dev/loop25p1 status=progress
```

I then take the `sha1sum` of the original and recreated file.

```
sha1sum /tmp/image.dd.raw 
0d31163796cda45e016f5f1459426adb4a872b57  /tmp/image.dd.raw

sha1sum /tmp/image.raw 
d961e97b63472cd3f317f8823de68508e583f713  /tmp/image.raw
```

Why do these differ?

Comment: What is the output of `</tmp/image.dd.raw wc -c`? What is the output of `</tmp/image.raw wc -c`?

Comment: (1) Is it possible the filesystem (if any) you have written to `/dev/loop25p1` got mounted automatically? (2) Is it possible something else wrote to `/dev/loop25p1` after the first `dd` started and before the second `dd` finished? (3) Is it possible something wrote to `/dev/loop25` at that time? (4) Is it possible at that time something wrote to the regular file associated with the loop device?

Answer (score 3):

Hypothesis: `/tmp/image.raw` is smaller than `/dev/loop25p1`.

`/dev/loop25p1` is a block device with a certain size. It had its size even before you wrote anything to it. Copying a smaller file to a block device does not and cannot truncate it.

My guess is `/tmp/image.raw` is smaller than `/dev/loop25p1`. After copying the former to the latter, the latter contains the data from the former plus whatever was already there beyond the size of the former. In other words your first `dd` did not overwrite the whole `/dev/loop25p1` because it reached the end of its input before it reached the end of its output.

When you copied `/dev/loop25p1` to `/tmp/image.dd.raw`, you got all the data from the block device, including the part the first `dd` never got to. The images *are* different because of this "tail" in `/tmp/image.dd.raw`.

If you do

```
cmp /tmp/image.raw /tmp/image.dd.raw
```

you will get

```
cmp: EOF on /tmp/image.raw after byte …
```

which means that up to the end of `/tmp/image.raw` the files are identical, but the other file contains more bytes.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't considered that.  I've never used that tool before.

In my case it gave "differ: byte 1, line 1" Im surprised this happens so early I would have presumed it happened at the tail..

Comment: @bearrito This means my hypothesis is false, it does not match your case. I still think it's a plausible hypothesis in general.